# Make narrow characters with CSS

Tags: css, fonts, width

How do I reduce characters' width of Arial-like fonts with CSS?

Comment: I think it is possible in CSS 3 but not CSS 2

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't reduce character width, but you can reduce letter-spacing.

```
span {
 letter-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Comment: also takes decimal fractions (e.g. 0.2px) and negatives (e.g. -1px, -0.2px), so you can get some pretty fine-grained control.

Comment: oh, and different units, so it can be size-independent: -1%, -0.01em -- handy if the text in question varies in size.

Comment: @Val, I don't know what browser you are/were using, but decimal fractions don't appear to work in Chrome 21 three years later.

Comment: @JohnK, looks like you're right -- I think I was using FireFox then; it did and still does support decimal fractions. But not Chrome, and I assume other WebKit browsers. Good catch, I should have been more specific.

Comment: I believe, the answer should be: `letter-spacing: -1px;`, as with `0px` we don't get any letter-spacing reduction. Font remains unchanged. And yes, as of now (Chrome 26) Chrome still doesn't support fractions here.

Comment: @trejder As of now (several years later) it seems Chrome now does

Answer (score 29):

Use narrow fonts in your font-family declaration. These are pretty common.

`font-family: "Helvetica Narrow","Arial Narrow",Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;`

Answer (score 17):

Streching a font will be possible with the [`font-stretch` property of CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-width-the-font-stretch-property).

Comment: but not supported with Webkit browsers (Google Chrome, Apple Safari, ...)

Comment: @PrimozRome That’s why I used future tense.

Comment: Just a comment about font-stretch: font-stretch, supported by Firefox and IE, doesn't expand or shrink an arbitrary font. It merely chooses the most appropriated face inside a given font. It won't solve the original problem magically in any case. See [Explanation about how font-stretch really work in CSS Fonts 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-stretch).

Comment: It is still not supported, 6 years passed since the answer. Thank you for the answer anyway. :)

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Not quite: [Can I use … CSS `font-stretch`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-font-stretch)

Comment: Right, it was not working for me in Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.132, and it is working in Firefox 38.0 https://jsfiddle.net/gsqLcder/ Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can just scale your text. For instance:

```
.narrow {
    transform: scaleX(0.5);
}
```

but beware of `transform-origin` which can make your text move elsewhere (for example if you scale it with an origin at its center).

Comment: I used `transform` in FireFox 54 for the text in a `SELECT` element.  It correctly scaled the text inside my `SELECT` element and drew the `SELECT` element correctly, but it failed to adjust the spacing between objects.  The `SELECT` element takes the same space, even though it's considerably smaller horizontally.

Comment: Ancient question, but I wanted to add another tip for others who might find it useful: word wrapping will be applied *before* the scaling takes place, which may lead to undesirable excess whitespace. To compensate, apply `width: 200%` on the element as well (or the reciprocal of the scaling factor, more specifically).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `font-weight:` in your css code for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [font-stretch CSS property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-stretch.asp):

```
font-stretch: condensed;
```

Browser support seems to be limited – see e.g. the comments to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1161287/1523648) – but it worked for me in Firefox 61.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3: simply use `transform` and `transform-origin` combined:

```
transform: scaleX(0.85);
transform-origin: 0 100%;
```

the value of scaleX is your sought horizontal stretch rate (< 1 for condensing, > 1 for expanding).

cross-browserness: FF16, C36, S9, O23 [»»](https://caniuse.com/?search=transform)

**for example:**

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('condensed').style.transform = 'scalex(0.85)';
  document.getElementById('condensed').style.transformOrigin = '0 100%';
};
```

```css
#condensed {
  font-family: Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,'Liberation Sans',sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div><div id="condensed">don't shout it — do something about it!</div></div>
<button id="button">condense me!</button>
```