# How do I consistently size a font that is itself smaller than the standard?

Tags: css, fonts, web, font-size, typography

My problem is that I am using a locally-hosted webfont (which we'll call Gothic) and the font-size I apply in the stylesheet has a dramatic effect on the backup fonts declared.

Example, using imaginary numbers for ease:

Gothic is sized at 48, px or em, takes up about a width of 300px. Backup font Arial, if it loads instead for whatever reason, at 48 px or em, loads at a width of about 1200 pixels.

I have never seen a typeface behave like this which makes me wonder if the strangeness is due to the construction of the file format, but I am unsure. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: You'll need to provide the CSS that you're using.

Comment: Font size defines the _height_ of the glyphs, not the width. Different fonts have different average width, and thus the rendered text might have vastly different total width between fonts. Take a look at the [`font-size-adjust` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-fonts-20120823/#propdef-font-size-adjust), but apparently browser support is very poor.

Comment: @lanzz I am using an ultra condensed typeface, Dharma Gothic, so that theory seems plausible. Any workarounds?

Comment: You should specify a better backup font.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161242/make-narrow-characters-with-css  The safest solution overall would be to use an image (or dynamically use that as a fallback if you're feeling ambitious), or use a slightly older workaround like Cufon.

Comment: Thank you for this advice; I'll do some homework at better alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, take a look at browser's [@font-face support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface) and note that:

- EOT format is supported by IE only
- WOFF is supported by any browser but IE8
- SVG is not supported by IE and Firefox
- TTF/OTF is well supported by any browser but IE

Do you cover any browser?

Then you need to provide a fallback for browsers not supporting @font-face at all.

I suggest you to include [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-cssclasses-teststyles) on your document's head section.

---

Select **@font-face** and **Add CSS classes** on Modernizer's download page, or follow this [download link](http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-cssclasses-teststyles).

Modernizer adds classes to your page's `<html>` element, so you can use this classes to override settings for browsers not supporting a specific feature.
This rule will apply to the whole document:

```
.no-fontface {
    font-size:16px; /* the font size value for Arial only */
}
```

It must be placed **below** any other `font-size` rule.
Alternatively, you can declare `font-size:16px !important;` and put the rule anywhere in your stylesheet. It will not be overwritten (except by other rules using `important!` of course).

If you want to target a specific element, you've to put `.no-fontface` at the beginning of the selector. For example:

```
.no-fontface #header h1 {
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Comment: Modernizr seems to be the easiest solution to implement; the typography I am using for my headlines is simply too unique for anything web safe. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want to choose a group of fonts with similar proportions for your *font stack*.  If there's no font that you can expect on any OS that's similar to your preferred font, then there's not really you can do at this point in time.

Font-sizes are not something you can rely on anyway, as users can and will modify this.  What happens to your designs when they do?